# Please help me to debug this code

Tags: php, mysql

Bit confused with this one.

Basically, I have a column in a table, and I want to retrieve the value in that column, for a specific row.

I have one set of code that works, but not in this particular situation.

The code I have that works is this:

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username='$login' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
```

This obviously retrieves that particular row, and then:

```
$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['User ID'];
```

This successfully sets the session variable, as the value from the user id column from this row.

So that's fine, that works. The code I am trying to use in my new situation is this:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM vote WHERE Username = '" .$_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']. "'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
```

This gets the row based on the current user, and then:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
 { 
 Print "<b>Name:</b> ".$row['Username'] . " <br>"; 
 Print "<b>Vote:</b> ".$row['Vote'] . " "; 
 }
```

The while loop works correctly, it displays the current username, and their vote. Obviously I felt the loop was not required as I already have just the one row selected. Removing the loop broke it, so I put it back. Not a big deal, I can live with that if it gets the job done.

The issue I am focusing on, is the use of the

```
$row['Username']
```

In this if statement:

```
 if($row['Username'] == "Admin") {
 echo ("Win!<br />");
 }
 else {
 echo "Failed!";
 }
```

When printing from the loop above, it prints:

```
 Name, as Admin, 
and vote, as 0.
```

If I then try to validate using the if statement, I ask it to echo Win! if the username == Admin.

Obviously it is true as it has printed it on the line before, however, it always prins Fail! and I can't understand why.

Should I set $row['Username'] as some other variable?

Can anyone offer their guidance please?

Cheers

Eds

Comment: your loop should not output as you show. Please double check the codes you posted

Comment: strange, it should works. like @pritaeas said, change while to an if, and an else that shows `mysql_error()`.

Comment: Thanks guys, it definately did output the above, and the code is a direct copy and paste from my page. Have changed while, to if and all is working correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from your loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
 { 
 Print "<b>Name:</b> ".$row['Username'] . " <br>"; 
 Print "<b>Vote:</b> ".$row['Vote'] . " "; 
 }
```

The first time through, `$row` is set to the row of data from the database.  It then tries to go through the loop again, but since there is only one row, `mysql_fetch_array` returns `false`.  now `$row` is set to `false`.  So any code after the loop won't have access to the data anymore.

The solution would be to replace your loop with a simple if statement:

```
 if ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
 { 
   Print "<b>Name:</b> ".$row['Username'] . " <br>"; 
   Print "<b>Vote:</b> ".$row['Vote'] . " "; 
 }
```

Comment: That did the trick! thanks! is there anyway for me to remove the if statement completely, and just set that value as a variable that I can work with?

Comment: dont worry, i set the variable from within the if statement! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see how your PHP code could produce that "it prints" sample. However, check that your `Username` field actually contains an exact "Admin" string. It may have a linebreak or other whitespace in it. Doing a

```
var_dump($row['Username']);
```

should show something like

```
string(5) Admin
```

The bracketed number (5) is the length of the string. If it's not 5, then you've got some extra stuff in the string causing the `== 'Admin'` test to fail.